# How to download multiple files without zipping

Tags: java

We are using select all button for selecting the multiple files from UI.

Here we are downloading files one by one and finally making zip of all files and sending to user.

The problem here is user is waiting for long time,example if he downloads 30 files say takes time 20 minutes .IF he has work with first file still he need to wait for 20 minutes till he get zip.

So our idea give one after another file response to browser.

Here we are using one request i.e., select all button and we want 30 file responses this is one after another without zipping(as we get the file path we want to send to browser and the repeat till all files are done).

I Know the basic rule 'single request and single response'.

But is it possible to achieve this in  java with advanced technologies.

I new to java please help me.

Comment: You can make a custom page that pings your server and lets the client know when each download is ready. Btw, none of your tags are relevant to the question.

Comment: Hello Naveen i don't know details ,how you have implemented your code on client end now. But  you must be sending filenames to server end. Now  what you can  do is submit each file name as form parameter to server one by one and target your form response to an iiframe by setting target attribute of form to iframe.hope this will help.

Comment: tq sunil kumar will try this ....

Comment: @naveen you find it suitable please up vote.